# Detect click outside some elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking for some solutions to solve this problem, but nothing helps

Here is my JavaScript code

```js
var specifiedElement = document.getElementById('a');
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);
  if (!isClickInside) {
    alert('You clicked outside A and B')
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #aaa;
  height:2em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

(In JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1zj9dmq7/)

I want when I click div a/b element, the "alert" function will not run, just running when clicked outside of that 2 elements, and **without jQuery**

Maybe someone can help me please, Thank You

Comment: Well, right now you're only selecting `#a`, you have to select `#b` too if you want to check it as well.

Comment: Plus one for the "without jQuery" bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var isClickInside = a.contains(event.target)||b.contains(event.target);
  if (!isClickInside) {
    alert('You clicked outside A and B')
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1zj9dmq7/1/

Answer (score 4):

You just have to check `event.target.id` to see if id matches any of the two div's `id`

```js
var specifiedElement = document.getElementById('a');
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  //var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);
  //console.log(event.target.id);
  if ((event.target.id != 'a') && (event.target.id != 'b')) {
    alert('You clicked outside A and B')
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #aaa;
  height:2em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the event object to get the `id` of the element from where the event is triggered.If it is neither a or b then alert it

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id !== 'a' && event.target.id !== 'b') {
    alert('You clicked outside A and B')
  }

});
```

```css
div {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

Comment: Wrap the text in span or p or other content element and won't work due to target will be the child when clicking on that span

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `focusLost` event. I am sure it's available in jQuery, but I don't know its exact name.